How to bake normal map without projection?
I need to bake normal map, but I need it only for further using in game engine with the same model, so I don't need to use Selected to Active or Cage options. All I need is to get rid of this

and replace it with normal texture. But when I'm trying this way

with selected mesh, I'm getting this texture with obviously unwanted green areas:

Here's the way how I'm connecting this texture (strength doesn't do anything, except of body color changing)



What am I doing wrong?
Here's the .blend file (NSFW!)

P.S. The link is missing (don't know why), so here's the proper link

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

@Jakemoyo I've tried to clear it as much as I could with recursive method, but file is still 108 Mb, so blend-exchange can't handle it. Is there any way to share it?

Put only the parts relevant to your question into a separate blend file and see if that helps?

@Jakemoyo I've deleted almost everything, but finally uploaded it. Please, check it when you have time (file is NSFW).

Looks like your problem is coming from a few different spots that I don't think I can 100% solve myself.

You've got doubled verts so that probably isn't helping much get rid of those.

Your current Normal output is coming from several procedural and baked sources mixed together. which doesn't seem to have any data on the fingernails and face. This seems to be causing the green mesh issue. You can see this by using Ctrl+Shift+LMB to preview that map.The face and fingernails are clearly not matching the rest of the model.



To test this theory I just used the default Geometry Normal output and used the original Normal as a mask to blend between the two.

This seems to fix most of the issues in the baked Normal map.

These little green parts still remaining are mainly caused by pixel dilation, maybe also from the geometry on the fingernails. Seems like there might be some non-manifold or overlapping geo in those parts. I'll let you figure that out.

I wouldn't recommend that you use this exact technique as the solution, I just wanted to confirm that your problems with the bake are caused by the lack of data in the original map, which seems to be the case.

The face has different material, I just deleted it to clear the file. So, in this case, the problem is just in fingernails (if we are exclude the face part)? Or I understood you wrong?

Yes I would say that's probably it. I don't know how exactly the baking process works when there's no HP to LP transfer, but everything I know about normal baking would mark that geo as problematic.
